# Using Composite Newton-Cotes integration rules in Mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to learn how to integrate functions using composite newton-cotes. In other words, I want to divide the interval we are integrating over into $n$ equal subintervals, and then apply Newton-Cotes on each. For example if I wanted to integrate $f(x)$ over $[0,1]$ with $n$ intervals with Simpsons rule, I would split $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal intervals and apply Simpsons rule on each interval and the sum is the approximation of the integral. I do not know how to input this into Mathematica. I found an official reference here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#81663330
However, not only does the "Points" option not work (so I cannot pick which rule I should use, luckily n=3 is default which is the Simpsons rule), I am not sure how to do composite NC. Do I have to manually write the sum of integrals over each interval and then make Mathematica integrate each one using NC? I feel like there must be an easier solution.

Comment: This works: `NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"NewtonCotesRule", "Points" -> 5}]`

Comment: Maybe you want to do this?: `n = 2;
NIntegrate[x^7,
 Evaluate@Flatten@{x, Subdivide[0., 1., n]}, 
 Method -> {"NewtonCotesRule", "Points" -> 5}, MaxRecursion -> 0]`

Comment: @MichaelE2  ohhh the "points" go into the method! I thought it was an option of NIntegrate. I think the first code you posted just does the interpolation quadrature with polynomial of degree 4 rather than what I want. I think the second code works, could you explain a little bit how it works?

Comment: In the question, you wrote, "I would split [0,1] into   equal intervals...". You can specify intervals in `NIntegrate` with `{x, x0, x1,..., xn}`.  `Subdivide[0., 1., n]` will split [0, 1] into `n` equal intervals.  Just evaluate `Evaluate@Flatten@{x, Subdivide[0., 1., n]}` separately with different values of `n` to see what you get.  `MaxRecursion -> 0` keeps `NIntegrate` from splitting the intervals further.  Is that what you want? I can put it in an answer, if so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the question, the OP writes, "I would split [0,1] into   equal intervals...".  It seems the OP wants to control precisely how Newton-Cotes is carried out. These things can be done in `NIntegrate` relatively easily.

You can specify subintervals in `NIntegrate` with an iterator of the form `{x, x0, x1,..., xn}`.  `Subdivide[0., 1., n]` will split [0, 1] into `n` equal intervals.  And `Flatten@{x, Subdivide[0., 1., n]}` will construct an iterator of the desired type.

Normally, `NIntegrate` will recursively split the intervals further until the error estimate on each interval satisfies the precision and accuracy goals.
Setting `MaxRecursion -> 0` keeps `NIntegrate` from splitting the intervals, and `NIntegrate` will simply apply Newton-Cotes to each subinterval and finish whether or not the goals have been met.

```
n = 2; 
order = 4;
NIntegrate[x^7,
  Evaluate@Flatten@{x, Subdivide[0., 1., n]},
  Method -> {"NewtonCotesRule", "Points" -> order+1},
  MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

It will give a warning message that includes the (numerical) error estimate. I like the message, but if you don't, you can use `Quiet` or set `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` extremely low (e.g. `-10`).

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to learn how to integrate functions using composite newton-cotes. In other words, I want to divide the interval we are integrating over into n equal subintervals, and then apply Newton-Cotes on each.

That describes `NIntergrate`'s (fairly well documented) [`MultiPanelRule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#106389821).

Here is an example of computing integral and error estimates directly with it:

```
Clear[F];
F[x_] := Sqrt[x];

tbl = Flatten[
   Table[
    Block[{absc, weights, errweights},
     {absc, weights, errweights} = NIntegrate`MultiPanelRuleData[{"NewtonCotesRule", "Points" -> npoints}, npanels, MachinePrecision];
     {npanels, npoints, Map[F, absc].weights, Map[F, absc].errweights}
    ], {npanels, 2, 10, 2}, {npoints, {2, 4}}], 1];

ResourceFunction["GridTableForm"][tbl, TableHeadings -> {"Number of panels", "Number of points", "Estimate", "Error"}]
```

[image]